# Save a sheet instead of a complete workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using following code to save an Excel workbook. Instead of saving complete work book, I just wish to save a sheet in this workbook named *Reconciliation*. All values in the sheet should be saved as values while keeping the formatting the same.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    ' Yes
    ' Code to save consumer wise mirs on the desktop

    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String

    On Error GoTo Err_Clear

    Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar\"

    filename = Range("A1")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    Err_Clear:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            MkDir CreateObject("wscript.shell").specialfolders("desktop") & "\rohailnisar"

            Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar\"
            filename = Range("A1")
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You would have to copy the worksheet to a new workbook you create, and then save that workbook, since worksheets cannot be saved all by themselves.

Comment: can this be done by modifying above code

Comment: All your code does is save a workbook, so since that's one of the things you would need to do, sure you can add to it.

Comment: Is the code in the same workbook? If not, is it open or closed? What will be the save-location, e.g. `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar\"`? What will be the new workbook's name (and format), e.g. `Reconciliation.xlsx`?

Comment: its from the same work book, its like a master file, and new file name should be the value in E1

Comment: Is the **code** in the same workbook? If not, is it open or closed? What will be the save-location, e.g. `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar\"`? What will be the new workbook's format, e.g. `.xlsm` or `.xlsx`? Is the file extension already in cell `E1`, e.g. `Test.xlsx`?

Comment: No sir, file extension is not in E1, its only the name of consumer by which i want to save the new file. and new file format should be .xlsx

Comment: What are *"mirs"*?

Answer (score 4):

### Export a Worksheet

- This saves a copy of a worksheet as the only sheet in a new workbook in the same folder. Before saving, it converts formulas to values. It is saved in the `.xlsx` format 'removing' any code.
- If the code is in the open (initial) workbook, then replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveWorksheet()
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Reconciliation")          

    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Dim BaseName As String: BaseName = sws.Range("E1").Value
    
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & BaseName & ".xlsx"
    
    sws.Copy

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    dwb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value = dwb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'dwb.Close

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook` can sometimes give unexpected results. Better to use `Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Interesting. Didn't encounter this issue so far. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, for some reasons there was some issue with BaseName = swb.Range("E1").Value. i changes it to BaseName = Range("E1") and it worked. one more thing, what is the same file name already exsit in the folder, i want it to replace older file with sam name.

Comment: What you fixed was my big mistake. You need to add the worksheet e.g. `swb.Worksheets("Reconciliation").Range("E1").Value`. I fixed it in this manner. I also added the overwriting without confirmation part that uses `Application.DisplayAlerts`.

Comment: thank you sir, it worked as needed, really appriciate your help. please if you can also look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447912/find-and-paste-values-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-selected-columns

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of saving complete work book, I just wish to save a sheet in this workbook named Reconciliation. All values in the sheet should be saved as values while keeping the formatting the same.

#### Code

```
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wsThis As Worksheet

Dim wbThat As Workbook
Dim wsThat As Worksheet

'~~> Change this to the workbook which has the Reconciliation sheet
Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets("Reconciliation")

'~~> This will create a new workbook with only Reconciliation
wsThis.Copy
    
'~~> Get that object. It will be last in the queue
Set wbThat = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
Set wsThat = wbThat.Sheets("Reconciliation")

'~~> Convert to values
wsThat.UsedRange.Value = wsThat.UsedRange.Value

'~~> Save that workbook
wbThat.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```