# Find and paste values from one sheet to another in selected columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste values from one sheet into another, both sheets have one unique column B "Bill ID".

I enter values in column p, q and w of sheet "reconciliation".

When I run the code it should paste these values in column p, q, w of bills sheet against same Bill ID, Bill ID in both sheets is in column 2.

One more thing, from reconciliation sheet for Bill ID, it should search only from b21 to last non empty row.

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsDisp As Worksheet: Set wsDisp = wb.Worksheets("Reconciliation")

Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim e As Long
Dim F As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = wsDisp.Cells(19, 16).Value
b = wsDisp.Cells(19, 17).Value
c = wsDisp.Cells(19, 23).Value

e = MsgBox("Do You Wish to Save Recovery ? " & vbNewLine & "GIDC PAID = " & a & vbNewLine & "GST PAID = " & b & vbNewLine & " LPS PAID = " & c, vbYesNo)

If e = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For i = 21 To 400
    Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 2), 16) = Sheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 16)
    Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 2), 17) = Sheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 17)
    Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 2), 23) = Sheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 23)
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Reconciliation Sheet
[image: Reconciliation Sheet]

Bills
[image: Bills]

Answer (score 0):

### Update Cells in Matching Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Updates the 'Bills' worksheet.
' Calls:        'RefColumn','GetRange'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub UpdateBills()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Reconciliation"
    Const sfRow As Long = 21
    Const suCol As String = "B"
    Const sColsList As String = "P,Q,W"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Bills"
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    Const duCol As String = "B"
    Const dColsList As String = "P,Q,W"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create references to the read-columns ('surg' and 'durg')
    ' and write only destination column to an array ('duData').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim surg As Range: Set surg = RefColumn(sws.Cells(sfRow, suCol))
    If surg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim durg As Range: Set durg = RefColumn(dws.Cells(dfRow, duCol))
    If durg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    ' This is not done for the source because 'Application.Match'
    ' is multiple times faster on a range.
    Dim duData As Variant: duData = GetRange(durg)
    
    ' Write values from the write-columns to jagged arrays.
    
    ' Split the lists (comma-separated strings) to arrays.
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    Dim dCols() As String: dCols = Split(dColsList, ",")
    
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(sCols)
    
    ' Define the jagged arrays.
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(0 To cUpper)
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(0 To cUpper)
    
    ' Define destination empty array ('drData').
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(duData, 1)
    Dim drData As Variant: ReDim drData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    ' Write values from the source write-columns to the source jagged array,
    ' and destination empty arrays to destination jagged array.
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        sData(c) = GetRange(surg.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(c)))
        dData(c) = drData
    Next c

    Erase drData
    
    ' Write matches from source (jagged) array ('sData')
    ' to destination (jagged) array ('dData').
    
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim sIndex As Variant
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        sIndex = Application.Match(duData(dr, 1), surg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(sIndex) Then
            For c = 0 To cUpper
                dData(c)(dr, 1) = sData(c)(sIndex, 1)
            Next c
        End If
    Next dr
    
    Erase duData
    Erase sData
    
    ' Write values from destination array tp destination ranges.
    
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        durg.EntireRow.Columns(dCols(c)).Value = dData(c)
    Next c

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

End Function
```